# Laravel 5.3 queue worker, stop after some time through Jenkins

Tags: laravel, jenkins, laravel-queue

In Laravel 5.3.

I'm running through jenkin a command of laravel:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

But I need to stop it. Ideally I would like to stop the worker after the queue jobs gets empty, but it's not possible on Laravel 5.3. So another option would be to stop the command after sometime, let's say 1 minute.

How can I stop a process running through jenkins after some time? or stop a php artisan command.

With `php artisan queue:restart` I can stop all the jobs so I tried:

```
php artisan queue:work
sleep 60; php artisan queue:restart
```

But that 2nd line will never get reached because the workers is still running.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2):

you can use some solution form solve it

1.

- You save server resources by avoiding booting up the whole app on
  every job.
- You have to manually restart the worker to reflect any
  code change you made in your application.

You can also run:

```
php artisan queue:work --once
```

2- This will start an instance of the application, process a single job, and then kill the script.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

The queue:listen command simply runs the queue:work --once command inside an infinite loop, this will cause the following:

- An instance of the app is booted up on every loop.
- The assigned worker will pick a single job and execute it.
- The worker process will be killed.

Using `queue:listen` ensures that a new instance of the app is created for every job, that means you don't have to manually restart the worker in case you made changes to your code, but also means more server resources will be consumed.

Comment: I don't get the use of `queue:listen`in my situation. I see that keeps running after executing it in the console. I need a way to stop it, or jenkins will faill at its pipeline of command

Comment: you can use ```php artisan queue:down``` and ```queue:up``` or 
```queue:pause``` and ```queue:resume```

Comment: if you use supervisor you can use 

``` 
supervisorctl stop all 

``` 
 and

 ```  
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:* 
 ```